# For loop to create the same table out of list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a 2x2 table out of a list of dataframes (which consist of more than 2 columns per df). However, I am getting a bit stuck by trying to do this with a for loop. Below some example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                  b = c("Pos", "Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg", 
                        "Pos", "Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg"),
                  c = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y"))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                  b = c("Pos", "Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg", 
                        "Pos", "Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg"),
                  c = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y"))
df3 <- data.frame(a = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                  b = c("Pos", "Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg", 
                        "Pos", "Neg", "Pos", "Pos", "Neg"),
                  c = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y"))

df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

The above example shows 3 dataframes that are exactly the same (so the output in this case should be 3 tables with the same values). I want to create a table of columns "b" and "c" for each dataframe. I was trying to do this through a for loop (see below)

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
  table[[i]] <- table(df_list[[i]][2], df_list[[i]][3])
}
```

However, this appears not to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you need `lapply(df_list, function(x) table(x[[2]], x[[3]]))` ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` with `table` :

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) table(x[[2]], x[[3]]))
```

Or using names of the column.

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) table(x$b, x$c))

#[[1]]
     
#      N Y
#  Neg 2 2
#  Pos 2 4

#[[2]]
     
#      N Y
#  Neg 2 2
#  Pos 2 4

#[[3]]
     
#      N Y
#  Neg 2 2
#  Pos 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rbind.data.frame` function:

```
new_df = rbind.data.frame(df1, df2, df3)
```

and then remove the column `a`:

```
new_df = new_df[,c('b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `count` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(df_list, ~ .x %>%
        dplyr::count(b, c))
```